# Advantages of Docker layer over plain OS

Tags: docker

I'm not realy good at administrative tasks. I need couple of tomcat, LAMP, node.js servers behind ngnix. For me it seems really complicated to set everything on the system directly. I'm thinking about containerize the server. Install Docker and create ngnix container, node.js container etc.

I expecting it to be more easy to manage, only routing to the first ngnix maybe a little bit hassle. It will bring me also possibility to backup, add servers etc. easily. Not to forget about remote deployment and management. And also repeatability of the server setup task. Separation will probably shield me from recoprocating problem of completely breaking server, by changing some init script, screwing some app. server setup etc.

Are my expectation correct that Docker will abstract me little bit more from the "raw" system administration.

Side question is there anywhere some administrative GUI I can run and easily deploy, start/stop, interconnect the containers?

**UPDATE**

I found nice note [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-run-nginx-in-a-docker-container-on-ubuntu-14-04)

> By containerizing Nginx, we cut down on our sysadmin overhead. We will no longer need to manage Nginx through a package manager or build it from source. The Docker container allows us to simply replace the whole container when a new version of Nginx is released. We only need to maintain the Nginx configuration file and our content.

Comment: The question is too ambiguous and invites to debates..

Comment: My problem is that I always break something and the undo/redo correctly part is really pain. So I guess for this use case at least the advantage of Docker usage is unexceptionable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes docker will do this for you, but that does not mean, you will no longer administrate the OS for the services you run.

Its more that docker simplifies that management because you:

1. do not need to pick a specific OS for all of our services, which will enforce you to offside install a service because it has been not released for the OS of your choice. You would have the wrong version and so on. Instead, Docker will provide you the option, to pick the right OS or OS version ( debian wheezy, jessie or ubuntu 12.x, 14.x 16.x ) for the service in question. (Or even alpine)
2. Also, docker offers you pre-made images to avoid that you need remake the image for nginx, mysql, nodejs and so on.  You find those on https://hub.docker.com
3. Docker makes it very easy and convenient to remove a service again, not littering your system by any means (over time).
4. Docker offers you better "mobility" you can easily move the stack or replicate it on a different host - you do not need to reconfigure the host and hope it to "be the same".
5. With Docker you do not need to think about the convergence of containers during their live time / or stack improvements, since they are remade from the image again and again - from the scratch, no convergence.

**But, docker also (con)**

1. Adds more complexity since you might run "more microservices". You might need a service-discovery, live configuration system and you need to understand the storage system ( volumes ) quiet a bit
2. Docker does not "remove" the OS-Layer, it just makes it simpler. Still you need to maintain
3. Volumes in general might feel not as simple as local file storage ( depends on what you choose )

*GUI*

I think the most compelling thing would match what you define a "GUI" is, is rancher http://rancher.com/ - its more then a GUI, its the complete docker-server management stack. High learning curve first, a lot of gain afterwards

Comment: This is what I'm looking for. I will still need to manage the container's OS, but at least I cannot break another container when doing so. The discovery note is off topic so far, as I will have just couple containers, which will not change often. Are there any specific cases where I will be forced to interact with the host OS, after the Docker is set? i.e. some access rights setting or some networking. I guess it is managed then purely in containers.

Comment: Less topics to cover if you skip using host-mounts. In general, docker-engine + docker-compose are the only tools you want on the host + a firewall (like shorwall 5 with docker support). The last topic you always want to be covered are backups, usually this is done on the host, no matter you "raid+1" and then "offsite backups with bareos", but yeah, backups are needed as usual. Nothing really application specific, thats the point ( much less variety ).

Answer (score 1):

You will still need to manage the docker host OS. Operations like:

- Adding Disks from time to time.
- Security Updates
- Rotating Logs
- Managing Firewall
- Monitoring via SNMP/etc
- NTP
- Backups
- ...

**Docker Advantages:**

- Rapid application deployment
- Portability across machines
- Version control and component reuse
- Lightweight footprint and minimal overhead
- Simplified maintenance
- ...

**Docker Disadvantages:**

- Adds Complexity (Design, Implementation, Administration)

**GUI tools available**, some of them are:

- Kitematic -> windows/mac
- Panamax
- Lorry.io
- docker ui
- ...

**Recommendation:** Start Learning `Docker CLI` as the GUI tools don't have all the nifty `CLI` features.